# Using joined results for Django model with legacy database schema

Tags: python, django, django-models, legacy, inspectdb

I'm using Django 1.6 to provide administrative functionality to a legacy database using Django's built-in admin feature.

I've used `inspectdb` to generate the models and cleaned them up appropriately, but there's one part that is bugging me.  The schema is designed in an awkward way, such that I have a table `customers`:

```
class Customers(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    billing_id = models.IntegerField()
    option1 = models.BooleanField()
    created = models.DateTimeField()
```

as well as `customer_data`

```
class CustomerData(models.Model):
    cust_id = models.OneToOneField('Customers', primary_key=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

The `customer_data` record always lines up 1-to-1 with the `customers` record, and there's too much legacy code to go back and change this.  Is this some way I can have a single Django model that joins the records so that I can have a `Customer` object that has `.first_name` etc. attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said you're using Django's built-in admin features. If so, then you can create a [`ModelAdmin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-objects) for `Customers` and then add `CustomerData` as an [`InlineModelAdmin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects). This will give you *"the ability to edit models on the same page as a parent model."*

In your case it would look something like:

```
from django.contrib import admin

class CustomerDataInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = CustomerData

class CustomersAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [CustomerDataInline,]

admin.site.register(Customers, CustomersAdmin)
```

This will allow you to edit the related fields `first_name`, `last_name`, and `phone` in the form of each `Customers`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Is there any way to represent those two tables in the same model?  In some cases we won't be using Django's Admin and may need to search based on customer attributes, and it would simplify the controller logic immensely to be able to filter a single model by fields on both of those tables.